# My divs heights do not scale with the background image(s)

Tags: html, css

I've checked everywhere that I can think of, no luck. I have a page I'm trying to make responsive.  Pretty much one div on top of the other with a css background image inside.  When I change the browser window size the image seems to scale pretty well but the div height doesn't so you can see the background of the div.  I need the div height to change in proportion to the image size.  I'm trying to use CSS only without javascript since I'm brand new to web design.    Any help would be great.

Here is the code I've got.

The HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>    

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>The Home Page</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The best toy out there">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>



<body>
<!--<h1> Body Text</h1>-->


<div id ="top_pic">
 <hgroup> </hgroup>
<h1> top_pic;  SOME TEXT WILL GO HERE</h1> 
    <!-- A logo image will also be placed on top of background image in this div probably     in the hgroup  -->

</div>

<div id = "middle_pose">  
<h1 class = "midposetext"> MIDDLE pose div, some text goes hereAAA</h1>
</div>
<div id = "content"> 
<h1> Content div...some text goes here</h1>
</div>

<div class = "footer"> 
<h1> Footer div</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
background-color : #e8e821;
width: 85%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
border: dotted black; 
position: relative;
padding: 1%;

}

#top_pic { 


background-image: url('images/eyeforheader1.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: solid #3fa85f; 
margin: 0 0 20% 0;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
display: block;




}

#middle_pose {
/*background-image: url('images/girl on back grasping sheets brunette.png');*/
background-image: url('images/Screen Shot 2014-02-10 at 11.47.48 PM.png');
background-size: 100%; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: #7547dd;
width: 100%;
height: 450px;
border: solid #f05858; 
margin: auto;


}

#content { 
background-image: url('images/Screen Shot 2014-05-28 at 5.52.03 PM.png');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
border: solid orange;
}

 .midposetext { color: #de4b8f;
} 

#middle_pose h1{
color: yellow;
z-index: 10;
font-size; 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file, you can change the #middle_pose background-size property:

```
from: 
    background-size:100%;

to: 
    background-size:cover;
```

This will scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the container's background is covered. However, this may force portions of the image to be out of the viewable area (at certain dimensions).  In this case, you may find that you want to use media-queries to adjust the container's dimensions and/or swap the image for one with more appropriate dimensions/aspect-ratio.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've tried that and I would agree the container's background is covered and it does stretch past the container.  That's not ideal (the background stretching past the container) but also the container's height doesn't change when the browser window changes which is what I'm tring to do.  background-size: 100%; allows the image to scale along with the container width but as the image height gets larger or smaller the div height stays the same.  Same thing happens with the other divs except the footer which I haven't tried yet.  Thanks though @birthnight